# Getting frequency of words from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, join, split, counter, strsplit

I have a dataframe that has the column cast which contains multiple actors from a movie. How do I count the number of times each actor appears in the dataset
This is a snippet of what the column looks like

```
df['cast'][:3]
0    João Miguel, Bianca Comparato, Michel Gomes, R...
1    Demián Bichir, Héctor Bonilla, Oscar Serrano, ...
2    Tedd Chan, Stella Chung, Henley Hii, Lawrence ...
Name: cast, dtype: object
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code snippet to find the count of 'Stella Chung' for example:

`" ".join(df['cast'].values).count('Stella Chung')`

UPDATE:

Here's an explanation of what is being done:

- `df['cast'].values` returns a array containing all individual column values from the column named `cast`.
- `" ".join(array)` joins all the strings in the array together into a single large string
- `string.count(substring)` returns the number of time the substring occurs in the main string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please break it down and explain it in bits?

Comment: Updated the answer. If that solves your problem, feel free to accept the answer (tick mark below the voting section)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. it now makes more sense to me and yeah it's helped me

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Comment: Oh, ok I've done that